# Rails server readline error when including Guard gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, readline, guard, spork

I've bundle installed with the following gemfile:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-inotify', '~> 0.9'
  gem 'libnotify', '0.5.9'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

When I start the rails server at my terminal, I get the following error:

> steven@steven-VirtualBox:~/Dev/test_app$ rails s
>
> You're running a version of ruby with no Readline support
>
> Please `gem install rb-readline` or recompile ruby --with-readline.

I've tried installing readline as per the console directions but I get the same error. I found that if I remove guard-rspec and guard-spork, rails server starts fine. Here's what I'm running:

- ubuntu 12.10
- ruby 2.0.0
- rails 3.2.12
- guard-rspec 1.2.1
- guard-spork 1.2.0
- spork 0.9.2

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like readline isn't supported by ruby 2.0 since it is still very new(less than a month  since it was released) I would recommend using version 1.9.3 for now. Looking at guard-spork doc's https://github.com/guard/guard-spork and guard-rspec docs https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec. It says that it is tested for 1.8.7, 1.9.2, and 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this: [wrapping 0.5.0 release](https://github.com/luislavena/rb-readline/issues/79), it seems they are preparing a new release to support `ruby 2.0`, in the meantime you could try this:

```
git clone https://github.com/luislavena/rb-readline.git
cd rb-readline
rake install
```